# Compose Multiplatform without JVM? (native windows executable)

Tags: java, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

In theory, with `kotlin multiplatform` you can compile an executable for Windows, which not depends on a `JVM` installed to be executed. It's completly native.

Now I disscovered `Compose Multiplatform` for developing GUIs for `kotlin multiplatform`. And it supposedly can develop for Windows also. But there is a problem, in the official website I can read this:

> Compose for Desktop targets the JVM

Does that mean that it's not possible using it for developing windows native code for `kotlin multiplatform`? it can only be used to develop java applications for windows which needs a `jvm` installed?

Can't find anything that confirms that in the `compose multiplatform` website.

https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/

Also something very rare, in the official github they have a sample, but it uses... androidx libraries!

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
import androidx.compose.ui.window.rememberWindowState
```

How can I use `compose multiplatform` for develop `kotlin multiplatform` windows native code code which not depends of a `JVM` installed? If its not possible, then, what can I use to build GUIs for `kotlin multiplatform` windows native code?

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean that it's not possible using it for developing windows native code for kotlin multiplatform?

Correct, at least today. You are certainly welcome to attempt to port Compose to use the Kotlin/Native for Windows, following along Compose for Desktop and Compose for Web. Compose for Desktop leverages [Skiko](https://github.com/JetBrains/skiko), which presently does not appear to have Kotlin/Native Windows support.

> Can't find anything that confirms that in the compose multiplatform website.

The [Getting Started page](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started) linked to from [the Compose for Desktop site](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-desktop/) states that JDK 11 is required.